# What is wrong with my javascript onclick and onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a simple quiz. I have this code, but the Javascript part doesn't work. CSS is okay, but when it comes to `onclick` and `onmouseover` nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
    body {
        background: url(bild.jpg);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -130px;
        margin-left: -500px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 30;
        color: black;
    }
    .b {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -130px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 30;
        color: black;
    }
    .c {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -30px;
        margin-left: -500px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 30;
        color: black;
    }
    .d {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -30px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 30;
        color: black;
    }
</style>
<title>Moseso.de Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    function overa() {
        document.getElementById("a").style.background="green";
    }
    function overb() {
        document.getElementById("b").style.background="green";
    }
    function overc() {
        document.getElementById("c").style.background="green";
    }
    function overd() {
        document.getElementById("d").style.background="green";
    }
    function outa() {
        document.getElementById("a").style.background="white";
    }
    function outb() {
        document.getElementById("b").style.background="white";
    }
    function outc() {
        document.getElementById("c").style.background="white";
    }
    function outd() {
        document.getElementById("d").style.background="white";
    }
    function true() {
        alert("Richtig!");
    }
    function false() {
        alert("Falsch");
    }
</script>

<button class="a" id="a" onmouseover="overa();" onmouseout="outa();" onclick"true();">Antwort A</>
<button class="b" id="b" onmouseover="overb();" onmouseout="outb();" onclick"false();">Antwort B</>
<button class="c" id="c" onmouseover="overc();" onmouseout="outc();" onclick"false();">Antwort C</>
<button class="d" id="d" onmouseover="overd();" onmouseout="outd();" onclick"false();">Antwort D</>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("a").style.background="#E6E6E6";
        document.getElementById("b").style.background="#E6E6E6";
        document.getElementById("c").style.background="#E6E6E6";
        document.getElementById("d").style.background="#E6E6E6";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It would be very nice if someone could answer my question because I tried many times. The script is German BTW :)

Comment: I don't think you can have a functions called `true` or `false` ? Open your browsers console to see the error reports.

Comment: Correct. `true` and `false` are reserved keywords. Use different identifiers for those function names.

Comment: You are right. Thanks :) Now mouseover works, but when i click, nothing happens. How to fix this?

Comment: Look at your html onclick attribute. It's missing `=` from `onclick="functionname();"`

Comment: Look at your end tags. `</>` is wrong. Oh, and do you have a doctype declaration?

Comment: Good find Mr Lister. I can't believe I didn't notice that while looking at the onclick attribute. You should close your button with `</button>` not `</>`

Comment: In addition, I'm not sure you can write shorthand CSS properties with JavaScript like `style.background="green"` . Use `style.backgroundColor="green"` just in case, even if it appears to work in your browser when testing.

Comment: Many of these become very apparent even in something as simple as [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Let tools help.

Comment: Oh, well i didn't see i forgot"=" Very stupid mistake. thanks anyway!

Comment: By the way, you can accomplish the same behavior of styling with CSS.  That would eliminate much of the javascript.  Why not use the :hover selector in CSS?  Such as  .a:hover {background: green}

Answer (score 1):

You can't use keywords such as true or false for function names.  To fix this error, change the true or false method names to something else.

Each button is missing a proper `</button>` closing tag.  Replace the `</>` with `</button>`

Also, you are missing the assignment operator for the onclick attribute.  Make sure an = appears after onclick and before the string assignment.

Comment: Technically, the violation of the use of reserved keywords is part of the answer, so it does not belong as a comment.

Comment: Short answer but doesn't offer much detail or recommendation how to fix the current source code. It does have multiple errors so people might down vote because this answer isn't offering a solid solution to the issue(s) in hand.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the multiple issues.  Of course, credit to Brennen, NewToJS, and Mr Lister :)